# How to create excel file by copying CSV files and running VBA macros remotely from Linux

Tags: linux, excel, vba, vbscript, ssh

I'm running some task on Linux which produces certain CSVs. Once they’re produced, I need to copy them into different sheets of an excel file and then run some VBA macros to generate a report. Since this has to be done multiple times a day (with no pre-defined/fixed schedule), I’d like to automate it.

Here is what I tried:
I wrote a VBScript, which takes the CSV files and other required input files, opens an excel file, copies the CSVs into the excel, runs some VBA macros, and saves and closes the result. This VBScript works fine when triggered locally on a windows server.

I have uploaded a simpler version of the files involved [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4ugWarhx5tMNlpVbnhtZWZvbVk/edit?usp=sharing) which somewhat clarify my requirements (Note that the macros I need to run are much more complicated (~500 lines) compared with the macros here).
There are four files inside the archive:

1. Template.xlsm: The Excel template of the report into which data is to be pasted
2. Input_Sheet2.csv : The input data to be pasted into the template into sheet 2
3. Input_Sheet3.csv : The input data to be pasted into the template into sheet 3
4. Run.vbs: The vbscript which triggers the “copy-paste” macro present inside the Excel template.

The command to run the VBScript is: ‘cscript //Nologo Run.vbs /NoCancel’

Now, in order to automate whole task, I thought to trigger this VBScript remotely from Linux over ssh. I installed the cygwin ssh daemon on the windows box and facilitated ssh connections from the Linux machine. This cygwin ssh connection from Linux allows to run several windows commands, but fails to run the VBScript and doesn't produce any excel output.

I can't figure out which component has limitations. Is it cygwin ssh not facilitating execution of VBScript? Is it VBScript not facilitating creation of files remotely? Is it ssh client on Linux not allowing opening of excel in GUI format? Or there is another way to automate this task from Linux.

Thanks,

Shubham

Comment: No error messages. It just hangs indefinitely until you force close it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd focus on:

1. Did you test running your script from the Cygwin Terminal? (I did try a simple script, that opened Execl (.Visible = True) successfully, so I *believe* your fears concerning cygwin not allowing to open the Excel GUI are unnecessary).
2. Do the sshd user account's path and cwd allow the short invocation "cscript Run.vbs" or should the long version "/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/cscript.exe /home/user/Run.vbs" be used?
3. Does the sshd user have access/permissions to all involved files and folders?
4. You didn't forget the unix file systems are case sensitive? (I did and wasted some time)?

Comment: Thanks Ekkehard,
1. Script runs well on triggering from cygwin command prompt locally on windows, but doesn't run when triggered remotely from Linux over ssh connection to cygwin daemon on windows.
2. It allows short invocation remotely. I tried running a simple VBScript with just 'Wscript.echo "My Very First Script"' in it, and it echoes well.
3. I have given full control to everyone over respective files and folders.
4. Not the case